# Can 4-pyridones be synthesised analogously to 2-pyridones?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds

I understand that 2-pyridone derivatives can be synthesized by oxidizing an *N*-methyl pyridinium salt with $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}$ under basic conditions. Can a similar method be used to produce 4-pyridones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reliable and old reference on the synthesis of 1-methyl-2-pyridone (*Org. Synth.* **1935**, *15*, 41, [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.15227/orgsyn.015.0041)) does not mention the formation of 1-methyl-4-pyridone as a side product and I doubt that it and can be formed that way.

The synthesis of 1-methyl-2-pyridone starts by reacting equimolar amounts of dry pyridine and dimethyl sulfate to form the N-methyl pyridinium salt. Then, the mixture is diluted with water and solutions of $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{K3[Fe(CN)6]}$ are simultaneously added.

This seems to do the trick: the $\beta$-amino alcohol formed by adding $\ce{OH-}$ *ortho* to the nitrogen atom is immediately oxidized, which prevents the opening of the pyridinium salt.

For the synthesis of 1-alkyl-4-pyridones, a somewhat classical approach would be to react the corresponding 4-pyranone with a primary amine under more or less drastic conditions, as shown in *Can. J. Chem*., **1976**, *54*, 3377.

Altenatively, *Grignard* reaction of a 2-substituted 4-benzyloxypyridine-N-oxide, followed by debenzylation/methylation with methyl triflate and subsequent treatment with $\ce{NaOH}$ will yield the desired a 1,2,5-trisubstituted 4-pyridone ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2010.06.019)).

Comment: Many thanks ! Do you know of any way to make 4-pyridone from pyridine (via n-oxides or otherwise) ?

Comment: @J.LS Do you mean the unsustituted parent 4-pyridone? I would buy its tautomer, 4-hydroxypyridine, and dissolve it in a somewhat polar solvent. In solution, the pyridone should dominate.